# Can't Open Python Script on Terminal

Tags: python, linux, flask, ubuntu-12.04

I kept on getting this error. I just can't open scripts on the terminal. My idle and my python console works. I do not want to copy and paste lines into my idle. 
I think python search in the wrong path...

I have ubuntu, please see below the terminal that I copy and paste

```
judy@ubuntu:~$ cd anotherproject
judy@ubuntu:~/anotherproject$ python hello.py 
python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
judy@ubuntu:~/anotherproject$ cd
judy@ubuntu:~$ cd Scripts
bash: cd: Scripts: No such file or directory
judy@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop
judy@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cd Scripts
judy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Scripts$ python passwordgenerator.py 
python: can't open file 'passwordgenerator.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
judy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Scripts$ ls
gemail.py   hello.py   passwordgenerator.py 
judy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Scripts$
```

here is my hello.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/') 
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Looks like you were just in the wrong directory.

Comment: Did you mean to add ~/anotherproject to the python path?

Answer (score 2):

1. hello.py is in `~/Desktop/Scripts/` , not in `~/anotherproject`.  try `python ~/Desktop/Scripts/hello.py`
2. you might not have the correct permissions set.  python runs as your current shell user, which might not be able to read the file because it is owned by another user.  try typing in `ls -alh` and show us the output.